# Ошибка при установке пакетов Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

При установке пакета появляется вот такая ошибка.

Ошибка:

```
----- Установка "simplecrypt" -----
Collecting simplecrypt
  Downloading simplecrypt-0.1.1.tar.gz (1.3 kB)
Installing collected packages: simplecrypt
    Running setup.py install for simplecrypt: started
    Running setup.py install for simplecrypt: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\skril\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8bcw7snh\\simplecrypt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\skril\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8bcw7snh\\simplecrypt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\skril\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mnt64w_k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Include\simplecrypt'
         cwd: C:\Users\skril\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8bcw7snh\simplecrypt\
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\skril\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8bcw7snh\simplecrypt\setup.py", line 47, in <module>
        'simplecrypt = simplecrypt.cli:cli',
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\skril\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8bcw7snh\simplecrypt\setup.py", line 20, in run
        raise Exception("You probably meant to install and run simple-crypt")
    Exception: You probably meant to install and run simple-crypt
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\skril\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8bcw7snh\\simplecrypt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\skril\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8bcw7snh\\simplecrypt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\skril\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mnt64w_k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Include\simplecrypt' Check the logs for full command output.
----- Не удалось установить "simplecrypt". -----
```

Comment: Какой командой Вы производите установку?

Comment: Я нажимаю "Окружения Python" - просмотреть все окружения, пакеты Python ищу пакет и нажимаю: выполнить команду pip install simplecrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неверно производите установку пакета. Откройте терминал или консоль и выполните:

```
pip install simple-crypt
```

Такого пакета, который Вы хотите установить не существует

[Ссылка](https://pypi.org/project/simple-crypt/)